# “Double-faced” vs “double-headed.”

Tags: meaning, synonyms

According to Collins Dictionary “double-faced” means ‘deceitful’.

Can both adjectives of the Title box be used interchangeably in the sense of deceit?

Comment: In the sense of "deceitful" the origin of the term is apt to be bogus coins that had "heads" on both sides.  But "two-faced liar" has acquired it's own connotations, mainly of a person who "flips" between different and conflicting versions of his assertions, depending on how he's being challenged.

Comment: Double-headed eagle—look it up.

Answer (score 1):

**Double-headed (adj):**

1. (of a train) pulled by two locomotives.

**Example:** Trains were double headed for most of the day with every possible combination of locomotive.

2. (of a weapon) having two cutting implements, typically one at each end of the shaft.

**Example:** a double-headed axe.
[(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/double-headed)

---

**Double-faced or two-faced (adj):** 
2. Tending to say one thing and do another; deceitful.

**Example:** were you double-faced—did you betray them?’

[(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/double-faced)

---

You cannot interchange 'double-headed' and 'double-faced' to mean 'deceitful'. They have different meanings.

You can use 'duplicitous' or 'two-faced' instead of 'double-faced'.

**Duplicitous (adj):** deceitful.
 [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/duplicitous)

**Two-faced (adj):** Insincere and deceitful. [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/two-faced)